# Error with bagImpute and predict from caret package

Tags: r-caret, imputation

I have the following when error when trying to use the `preProcess` function from the `caret` package. The `predict` function works for knn and median imputation, but gives an error for bagging. How should I edit my call to the predict function.

Reproducible example:

```
data = iris
set.seed(1)
data = as.data.frame(lapply(data, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.8, 0.2), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))

preprocess_values = preProcess(data, method = c("bagImpute"), verbose = TRUE)
data_new = predict(preprocess_values, data)
```

This gives the following error:

```
> data_new = predict(preprocess_values, data)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessing/imputation functions in caret work only for numerical variables.
As stated in the help of [`preProcess`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-86/topics/preProcess)

> x a matrix or data frame. Non-numeric predictors are allowed but will be ignored.

You most likely found a bug in the part that should ignore the non numerical variables which throws an uninformative error instead of ignoring them.

If you remove the factor variable the imputation works

```
library(caret)

df <- iris
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(data, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.8, 0.2), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))
df <- df[,-5] #remove factor variable
           
preprocess_values <- preProcess(df, method = c("bagImpute"), verbose = TRUE)

data_new <- predict(preprocess_values, df)
```

The last line of code works but results in a bunch of warnings:

```
In cprob[tindx] + pred :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

These warnings are not from caret but from the internal call to [`ipred::bagging`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ipred/versions/0.9-9/topics/bagging) which is called internally by `caret::preProcess`. The cause for these errors are instances in the data where there are 3 NA values in a row, when they are removed

```
df <- df[rowSums(sapply(df, is.na)) != 3,]

preprocess_values <- preProcess(df, method = c("bagImpute"), verbose = TRUE)

data_new <- predict(preprocess_values, df)
```

the warnings disappear.

You should check out recipes, and specifically [`step_bagimpute`](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_bagimpute.html), to overcome the above mentioned limitations.